# Colorbox doesn't work after injection of ajax page using scrolling down method

Tags: jquery, ajax, scroll, colorbox

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a.ajax").colorbox();

    function last_msg_funtion() { 
        var ID = $(".picturebody:last").attr("id");
        $("#last_msg_loader").html('<img src="Pictures/loader.gif">');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "scrollingajax.php",
            data: "lastmsg="+ ID, 
            cache: false,
            success: function(html){
                $("#content").append(html);
                $("#last_msg_loader").remove();
            }
        });
    };

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
            last_msg_funtion();
        }
    });
});
```

The `$().colorbox();` just didn't function after loading part of the webpage into the original webpage using scroll down to load more result method. Newbie here, so sorry about asking this question. How may I get the colorbox function register after loading more result into the html using ajax? Thanks a lot!

Comment: It is really hard to figure out what you're asking. Please, edit for a bit of clarity - realize that this is the first time we've ever looked at the problem. Additionally, you might consider selecting a slightly different display name.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `$("a.ajax").colorbox();` again after you call `$("#content").append(html);`.  The new content doesn't have any event listeners bound to it when you insert it into the document.

Comment: I try to add additinal $("a.ajax").colorbox(); again after $("#content").append(html);, but still doesn't work. what has gone wrong?@@"

Comment: Do the `<a>` tags have the `ajax` class?

Comment: thats just the class assign to <a> it doesn't really matter, can be change to anything.